# Ubuntu boots to purple screen with Nvidia MSI 1080 and nomodeset

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia

I tried to solve this issue for about a week now, but can't seem to get around it. During installation had this same problem and nomodeset wasn't the solution, but had to install it switching to the Intel graphics. After the installation I kept using the Intel graphics, was able to boot and install the drivers, switch back to the Nvidia GPU, but still have to use nomodeset during every boot. 
Now that would be simple enough (and this post explains it how to do so: [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/38782#38782)), but still every single time I have to press enter at least to get it to boot or edit the grub entry and - without modifying anything - I can boot from there. This is super agonizing because I'm not always there and we tend to use the machine remotely and after every reboot someone has to go there and boot as explain above.

HW specs: Intel 7700 i7, MSI 1080, 16GB ram, 250GB SSD, UEFI only. (would love to post more details, but the box is down again and the office is closed for the weekend...)

I don't think that this is a duplicate as I couldn't find an exact problem and a solution around here, but if it is I apologize in advance.

EDIT: `/etc/default/grub/`

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: Yes, there is more that you need to supply.  Please supply your `/etc/default/grub`.  Also please indicate if you ran `sudo apt upgate-grub` after making the change.

Comment: Yes I know, but I just can't access the box right now. The <code> /etc/default/grub </code> is:
    GRUB_DEFAULT=0
    GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
    GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
    GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
    GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

Updated the grub of course and the <code>nomodeset</code> is present in the kernel line after rebooting and checking the entry.

Comment: I can't make out weather your output is formatted correctly.  If you would paste the same thing [here: Edit Your Question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1024874/edit) it would be easier to analyze.  Also, it'll make your issue clearer to others looking at the question.  How did you check the entry?  I understand you can't do it now, but when you get to the office run this: `cat /proc/cmdline` without manually adding it at boot.  You can use `Ctrl+Alt+F2` to get to a console, if the GUI doesn't work.

Comment: Yea sorry, updated accordingly.

Comment: Your response was quick.  I had mistakenly pressed ENTER when I was still editing my comment.  Can you elaborate on this:

 **How did you check the entry?** to verify the presence during boot? I understand you can't do it now, but when you get to the office run this: cat /proc/cmdline without manually adding it at boot. You can use Ctrl+Alt+F2 to get to a console, if the GUI doesn't work

Comment: Yea Ubuntu right now is screwing up my workflow so try to respond fast to get this out of the way so we can actually work eheheh. 
I see your point, but before I boot and hit "e" to edit the default entry and go down to the kernel line the nomodset entry is already there without me manually adding it and just press "ctrl+x" and it boots fine. It does not boot automatically tho. Will check the output of /proc/cmdline ASAP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76019/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-adathor).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, gave up on this one as it was greatly effecting our work-flow and installed Fedora 27. Everything works as expected.